# Why Exists and not exists return different results in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have been exercising SQL basic queries, however i am stuck on one task. I mean - I know how to do it, but when I try to apply reverse logic, something seems wrong and I can not understand what is making other query to produce wrong results. So the task is following:
“List the customers who have purchased a bike but not a helmet.”
So solving this issue by "NOT EXISTS" is quite simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.customerid) 
FROM salesordersexample.order_details od
JOIN salesordersexample.products p ON od.productnumber = p.productnumber
JOIN salesordersexample.categories c ON c.categoryid = p.categoryid
JOIN salesordersexample.orders o ON od.ordernumber = o.ordernumber 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(o2.customerid) 
    FROM salesordersexample.order_details od2
    JOIN salesordersexample.products p2 ON od2.productnumber = p2.productnumber
    JOIN salesordersexample.categories c2 ON c2.categoryid = p2.categoryid
    JOIN salesordersexample.orders o2 ON od2.ordernumber = o2.ordernumber 
    WHERE p2.productname LIKE '%Helmet%' AND o.customerid = o2.customerid
) 
AND p.productname ILIKE '%bike%';
```

But when i wanted to use EXISTS, I thought that exchaning LIKE to NOT LIKE in subquery will be enough, and my logic is guiding me strongly towards this idea. I am trying to understand what is happening, but I have no clue. Not working properly query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.customerid) 
FROM salesordersexample.order_details od
JOIN salesordersexample.products p ON od.productnumber = p.productnumber
JOIN salesordersexample.categories c ON c.categoryid = p.categoryid
JOIN salesordersexample.orders o ON od.ordernumber = o.ordernumber 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(o2.customerid) 
    FROM salesordersexample.order_details od2
    JOIN salesordersexample.products p2 ON od2.productnumber = p2.productnumber
    JOIN salesordersexample.categories c2 ON c2.categoryid = p2.categoryid
    JOIN salesordersexample.orders o2 ON od2.ordernumber = o2.ordernumber 
    WHERE p2.productname NOT LIKE '%Helmet%' AND o.customerid = o2.customerid
) 
AND p.productname ILIKE '%bike%';
```

First query return correct results - 2 rows, while the second one is wrong and returns 27 rows.  I am deeply convinced that the problem is trivial, but I can't understand why the results is wrong.

Comment: "purchasing any product that is not a Helmet" (to paraphrase what `productname NOT LIKE '%Helmet%'` does) is not the same as "not purchasing a helmet"

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` - and `distinct` inside a sub-query used for EXISTS or NOT EXISTS is useless anyway

Comment: How do the manual & other Q&A about this defining IN & EXISTS not answer this?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two subqueries are not logically equivalent.

In the first query, the `not exists` subquery ensures that the customer did not buy a helmet - that is what you want.

In the second query, `exists` checks that they at least purchased something that is not a helmet - regardless of whether they did or did not purchase a helmet. But since the rest of the query ensures that they did buy a bike already, the subquery always finds a matching row (the bike purchase). In a nutshell, the `exists` condition does not filter out any row, and the query just returns all customers that bought a bike.

Notes:

- `(not) exists` checks if any row matches, so `select distinct` is superfluous: `select 1` is sufficient. The database probably does the optimization for you under the hood anyway, but being explicit is better practice and makes the query easier to follow
- We could phrase the logic with `group by` and filter with a `having` clause, which would avoid the need to repeat the joins in the subquery